# Does jheidisql alpha 4r2 support Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i created a stored procedure using Heidisql 4.0 in Windows system. Now server system has been changed to linux. So i installed jheidisql alpha 4r2. I cant create stored procedure in it. Is there any other way to create stored procedure in linux environment for Mysql

Is there any stable version for Linux. Plz help me. Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try jHeidi, a java implementation of HeidiSQL, so it is multi platform.

Download jHeidi linux binary.
http://www.heidisql.com/jheidi/

MySQL Query Analyzer is another good option.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html